# Firebase Hosting Automatic Cache Busting with Bundle hash change in .js file /service-worker.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, create-react-app, firebase-hosting

At the moment I am using this setup in my firebase.json file, the service-worker.js file would cause the bundles to be cleared out of cache and downloaded fresh but it required a hard control+R refresh to do so, it didn't happen automatically, and my wildcard pattern matching on **/*.@(js|css) is now causing my rule for no-cache on /service-worker.js to not work either, but it is no good to force the user to hard refresh control+R whenever I deploy the next version, I need a better solution than setting max-age on my bundle to 0.

Any ideas?

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "value": "*"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(js|css)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=86400"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=604800"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/service-worker.js",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar question but I figured out how to. NOTE in my case Service Worker file is `sw.js`. You can find my config below. I just added separate rule for `sw.js` before wild card rule matching all the JS and CSS files:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=7200"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "sw.js",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=0"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "*/*.@(js|css)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=3600"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "manifest.json",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=86400"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```